# SQL; select last record each group

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

My table looks like this:

```
id userid score
1 10 55
2 10 89
3 10 70
4 15 50
5 15 80
6 17 90
7 17 99
```

I need such an SQL statment, which selects LAST `score` for each `userid`. This should get selected:

```
id userid score
3 10 70
5 15 80
7 17 99
```

any ideas? Thanks

P.S. I use SQLite3

Comment: you must add tag, which db you use. Certainly, with `partition` and `order by`, this is easy. Or even `RANK`

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned by T.S.  some sort of windowing function. here is one with row number
assuming your id can be used to determine what is "last"

```
with t as
 (select m.*,
  row_number() over (partition by userid order by id desc) as rn
  from mytable m
)
select id, userid, score from t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to this issue by first sorting the table in ascending order of `userid` and descending order of `id`.
Then grouping the values of the `inner` selection by the outer `userid`

The inner selection

```sql
SELECT inner.* FROM table AS inner ORDER BY userid ASC, id DESC;
```

will give you this intermediate result:

```sql
id  userid  score
--  ------  -----
3   10      70   
2   10      89   
1   10      55   
5   15      80   
4   15      50   
7   17      99   
6   17      90
```

Grouping this result by the `userid` will give you the outcome you want.

```sql
SELECT outer.* FROM 
  (SELECT inner.* FROM table AS inner ORDER BY userid ASC, id DESC) AS outer
GROUP BY outer.userid;
```

This gives you:

```sql
id  userid  score
--  ------  -----
3   10      70   
5   15      80   
7   17      99
```